# UIViewController Subclass, forward delegate message

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have UIViewController subclass, in which I implement a delegate, I then implement the delegate method in my childviewcontrollers (the viewcontrollers who inherits from the subclass), but I never receive a message, only if I implement the delegate method directly in the subclass/parent viewcontroller. I have set the delegate to self like so, from another viewcontroller, in prepare for segue.

.h

```
@interface aViewController : UIViewController 
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ModalViewDelegate> presentDelegate;
@end
```

.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ToView"]) {
        UITabBarController *tabBarController = segue.destinationViewController;
        for (UINavigationController *navController in tabBarController.viewControllers) {
            for (UIViewController *vc in navController.viewControllers) {
                if ([vc isKindOfClass:[SVC class]]){
                    self.SubclassVC = (SVC*) vc;
                    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setPresentDelegate:)]) {
                        self.presentDelegate = self.SubclassVC;
                    }

                    if ([self.SubclassVC respondsToSelector:@selector(setDismissDelegate:)]) {
                        self.SubclassVC.dismissDelegate = self;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@interface SVC : UIViewController <ModalViewDelegate>
@end

@implementation SVC
- (void)didPresentModalViewFrom:(UIViewController *)viewController {
// I recieve a message. Does work // How to forward this to childviewcontrollers?  
}
@end

@interface B : SVC
@end

@implementation B
- (void)didPresentModalViewFrom:(UIViewController *)viewController {
// Does not work
}

@end
```

How can I let childviewcontroller (the viewcontrollers that inherits from SVC) respond to the delegate method?

Comment: This is quite confusing. Can you clarify the inheritance hierarchy of your classes. It's difficult to tell what you mean by childviewcontroller, etc.